# Calling retrieve query by JDBCTemplate after jpa save method not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jdbctemplate

I faced a problem that calling retrieve query by `JDBCTemplate` after jpa save method not working.
I Have 8 jpa save method and after that a retrieve method using `JDBCTemplate` invoke, but retrieve(calling execute select) method not working means not return correct result but after thread.sleep(1000) or in debug mode it returns correct result.
Also, flush after saving not working.

Sample :

```
class serviceA{
A.save()
B.save()
C.save()
E.save()
ServiceB.execute()
}

class ServiceB{

execute("select data from A,B,C,D .....")

}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please share code configuration and describe what you want to achieve. Stating "it is not working" is hardly a proper description.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the question

Comment: That is pseudo code, not the reall code (please add it). You would need to flush all changes before calling the query **and** also make sure it runs in the same transaction, if not it will not see the data. I suspect the latter is the case (or a combination of both issues).

Comment: I used saveAndFlash but also not working

Comment: I hope you used `saveAndFlush`... But the comment was an **and**. I would also want you to add the actual code not psuedo code you have now as that will for sure be a dumbed down version.

Comment: Also, If I use  Thread.sleep(1000) it works correct. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: @M.Deinum The question updated

Comment: The problem is cucumber and improper transactional boundaries. Looks like you are abusing cucumber to test something that should be encapsulated in a single service method. The data setup should be done in a `@Given` annotated method and should run in a single transaction, so that after that method everything is stored. Yo have nothing related to transactions in there. It could also be me but I don't really see the added benefit here of cucumber but that could be just me.